# Ripping CD Audio simultaneously from 2 drives on one PC via USB or PATA - rip accuracy preserved?

Tags: audio, compact-disc, ripping

I'm considering ripping audio (reading audio) from CDs using 2 drives simultaneously to speed up the process of ripping the CDs - i.e. 2 at a time rather than 1. Are there any issues with achieving maximum rip accuracy?

In general I wondered if people have tried this and if the simultaneous streams from both rip activities would overload the host machine and cause packet loss or read retries resulting in a sub-standard CD-DA Audio CD rip?

If it just means the rip is slightly slower (but still faster than sequentially doing one rip followed by another) but still of maximum accuracy then that is OK for me.

I will be using dbPowerAmp to rip the CDs and converting to FLAC lossless format.

**Specific examples:**

There are 2 machines I intend to do it on:

1. A Toshiba NB100 1.6Ghz Atom netbook, 2Gb RAM, running Windows XP Home with 1 external LG DVD/CD burner and external 1 LG Blu-ray burner attached via USB 2.0, ripping to the machine's 5400rpm internal hard drive. This rips from one CD drive very well, more than adequate, it is a nippy, fast little machine for its specification.
2. A Desktop PC running Windows 7 Home Premium with MSI P4M900M2-L/ MS-7255v2.0 motherboard and 1.86Ghz Intel Core 2 Duo E6320, 7200rpm hard drive and 2Gb RAM, with an internal LG PATA DVD/CD burner (master) and a Philips DVD/CD burner (slave) on the same PATA bus (perhaps separate buses would be another option to consider here).

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this with two PATA drives in an older P4 machine (single core) with no issues. I start up two copies of my ripper/encoder, assign one to each drive and run. I get about a 50% performance increase. I was using Linux tools, but it should be the same under Windows.

Comment: By 50% increase, I mean two copies run at 1.5x, not double the speed of one copy.

Comment: +1 thanks. I'll be able to try out my situation to add to the experiences.